# How to return values that are NOT in a list, compared to other values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a production environment, trying to find a list of invoices that do not contain a specific item.

Example:

Invoice |  Item

```
    1 | Item A 
    1 | Item B 
      |        
    2 | Item A 
    2 | Item C 
    2 | Item D 
      |        
    3 | Item B 
    3 | Item D 
      |        
    4 | Item A 
    4 | Item C 
    4 | Item F
```

I'm looking for a query that will return all invoice numbers that do not contain Item B.

I could use NOT IN query, but I feel like that would return invoice numbers that do have Item B associated, but not in that row.

Any help is appreciated!

For the example, I expect the result to return Invoice numbers 2 and 4.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach uses aggregation:

```
SELECT Invoice
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Invoice
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Item = 'Item B' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Another approach would make use of a subquery of blacklisted items:

```
SELECT Invoice
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.Invoice = t1.Invoice AND t2.Item = 'Item B');
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where invoice = t.invoice and item = 'B'
)
```

If you want only the invoice numbers:

```
select distinct t.invoice
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where invoice = t.invoice and item = 'B'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
select t1.* 
from tblItem t1
where not exists 
(select *
                  from tblItem t2
                  where t1.Invoice = t2.Invoice
                    and Item = 'Item B');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option by avoiding NOT IN-

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT * FROM your_table
     WHERE item= 'Item B'
)B ON A.Invoice = B.Invoice
WHERE B.Invoice IS NULL
```